# Viewcontroller only presenting as Popover

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

When I `self.present` to the next VC programatically it always seems to come up as a popover.

I have a Viewcontroller (not embedded in the Navigation Controller or Tab Bar controller). I need to `self.present` to the Tab Bar controller programatically. I used the code below.

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController
            self.present(tabBarController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Not sure why they only come up as a popover as when I've tried this before it's worked fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've seen that question. The issue I'm having is that the destination VC is coming up as a popover instead of "fullscreen"

Comment: Then tell it that you want it to be fullscreen.

Comment: How do I do that? @matt

Comment: I gave you a link.

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Comment: Ask a clearer question then. I do not know what you are doing now. But I assure you that if you set your tab bar controller to be fullscreen and `present` it, it will be fullscreen.

Comment: My question is pretty clear. Where is the ambiguity?

Comment: Not sure why its not working then, let me try clean my build folder and restart Xcode etc

Comment: Well that seems to have made it work. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can make it as correct.